# Bold separate words in MVVM Prism Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bold

I show dialog page from ViewModel.I want to bold some words in message:
My code is down,and i want to bold word "Regija/e:".
     I try with tag "b" but dont work,is it some other possible way to do that?

```
 _pageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Prikaz trenutnih filtera", "Regija/e:" + IspisiRegijuVrednostFiltera + "\n" + "Format/i:" + IspisiFormatVrednostFiltera + "\n", "Zatvori");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could achieve it directly with `DisplayAlertAsync`,you maybe could consider [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup).

if you don't want use any 3rd party plugins,you could try to pop a new nav view onto the stack.

both methods you could refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042687/is-there-a-way-that-i-can-include-formattedtext-in-a-alert-with-xamarin-forms)